# mmenu open in desktop, closed in mobile, just like demo site

Tags: panel, mmenu

I would like the mmenu panel to be automatically opened in desktop mode, but only the menu icon to show in phone mode just like in the demo site http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/

I know I am not too bright but I can't find the answer in the documentation or in stack overflow. Please help

This is what I am doing.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
           var mq = window.matchMedia( "(min-width: 800px)" );
           if (mq.matches) {
                  $("#menu").mmenu({
                     offCanvas: false
                  });
                } else {
                  // window width is less than 800px
                }

       });
```

But it feels a little clumsy and it doesn't resize dynamically, just with a refresh.